# RegEx on Windows XP 32 vs Windows 2008 64 bit

Tags: regex, windows, vb.net

I have regular expression that works on windows XP (.NET 1.1), but not on Windows 2008 64(.NET 2.0) bit platform.

```
thisLine=""fname","lname","empid","password","User","Teller","login","Active","title","Jan 11 2012 12:00AM","MA","Retail","East","Market St","email@email.com","denied","approved","denied","denied","manager@email.com""
```

Can you please tell me why code below returns True on Windows XP 32 bit and false on Windows 2008 64 bit system:

```
MsgBox(RegexObj.IsMatch(thisLine, ",(?!(?<=(?:^|,)\s*""(?:[^""]|""|\\"")*,)(?:[^""]|""|\\"")*""\s*(?:,|$))"))

Dim m As Match = RegexObj.Match(thisLine)
Return RegexObj.Split(thisLine)
```

This should return array with `20` elements. Again, works fine on XP, why not on Windows 2008?

Comment: There is no technical reason it should not work. What version of .NET Framework are you using exactly?  You have declared `m` as a Match result, yet you never use it, explain this unused code.

Comment: I just extracted samples of my code. It's actually used in a function. Window XP runs 1.1 and 2008 server runs 2.0.

Comment: Have you used Visual Studio to debug the differenes in the actual result?  Have you looked up if there are differences in the RegEx capabilities between those two versions.  I suggest you think twice about using an almost unsupported version of the `.NET Framework`

Comment: That's legacy application, so i don't want to rewrite anything. Just need to move it over to Windows 2008 box. I even tried using this utility and yields same results as Windows XP machine - http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: you will be unable to just simply migrate it a 1.1 application to 2.0.  There are differences.  Have you compared the results, can you share the current output, all this can be done with Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you please confirm what exactly are you looking to see?

Comment: The current output....The expected output is already known.

Comment: RegexObj.Match(thisLine) returns false on Windows 2008 with .nET 2.0

Comment: Update your question with that information.  It shouldn't take 5 comments to get additional information.  The .NET Framework information should also be included so your comment can be deleted.

Comment: For a start, the `.Split()` method changed between .NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 - please see the remarks section of [Regex.Split Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx). For the `IsMatch` problem, I suggest you cut down your string and the regex to minimal parts and add back in in steps, examining the result in between to determine where the change in behaviour happens.

Comment: It looks like i had to replace quotes within regexp with double quotes again using replace method. Everything seems to be working now, thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like I still have a problem with this. Commas within values surrounded by double quotes get treated as a separate columns on 2.0 framework. How do i solve this? Thanks!